# Web Speech API for reading individual characters

Tags: reactjs, text-to-speech

I have tried `react-speech-kit` but my requirement is reading individual characters. I explored Web Speech API but couldn't find anything. If anyone knows any alternatives much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`tts-react`](https://github.com/morganney/tts-react) and just [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string before asking it to speak.

```js
import { useTts } from 'tts-react'

const SpeakCharacters = (text = '') => {
  const { ttsChildren } = useTts({
    children: text.split(''),
    autoPlay: true,
    markTextAsSpoken: true
  })

  return (
    <>{ttsChildren}</>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return <SpeakCharacters text="Speak these characters on render." />
}
```

If you want to speak the characters more slowly then you can do this:

```js
const SpeakCharacters = (text = '') => {
  const { ttsChildren, set, play } = useTts({
    children: text.split(''),
    markTextAsSpoken: true
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    set.rate(0.7)
    play()
  }, [set, play])

  return <>{ttsChildren}</>
}
```